# Complex Matrix Limit

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ complex matrix, show that if $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}||A^kv||=0$ for every vector $v \in \Bbb C^n$, then $|\lambda|\leq1$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$.

Comment: Your hypothesis is true for every vector $v$, as you said. Try to pick an eigenvector and see what happens in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Proof by contrapositive:  suppose there exists an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| > 1$, and corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$.  Consider $\lim_{k\to\infty} \|A^k \mathbf{v}\|$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\Vert A^k v \Vert \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ for every $v \in \Bbb C^n$.  If $0 \ne w \in C^n$ is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$, $A w = \lambda w$, we have

$A^m w = \lambda^m w,\tag{1}$

for every positive integer $m$, since

$A^2 w = A(Aw) = A(\lambda w) = \lambda (Aw) = \lambda^2 w, \tag{2}$

$A^3 w = A(A^2w) = A(\lambda^2 w) = \lambda^2 (Aw) = \lambda^3 w, \tag{3}$

and so forth.  Normalizing $w$, so that $\Vert w \Vert = 1$, we see from (1) that

$\Vert A^k w \Vert = \Vert \lambda^k w \Vert = \vert \lambda \vert^k \Vert w \Vert = \vert \lambda \vert^k, \tag{4}$

and

$\vert \lambda \vert^k \to 0 \; \text{as} \; k \to \infty \tag{5}$

if and only if

$\vert \lambda \vert < 1. \tag{6}$

Note we have actually shown something stronger than requested, i.e. that $\vert \lambda \vert < 1$, strictly.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***